# Spring auto wiring does not work with cucumber

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

Even though there is a component annotation the component object is not created.
Code to create a component
`@Component("customer")
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
@Lazy`

Code to access the component

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("customer")
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411591/how-to-integrate-spring-into-cucumber?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate Spring into Cucumber](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411591/how-to-integrate-spring-into-cucumber)